# One highly correlated variable swamps out other variables

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I modeled an SEM as follow:

> [image: SEM]

Attitude and Intention are highly correlated.

Without *Attitude* in my model, I have mostly significance and coefficients that support my hypotheses.

Once I add *Attitude* to the model, all variables but *Attitude* become insignificant. In some tests those variables switched direction as well making them contradictory. See some values below.

The sample size is n=150.
Convergent and discriminant validity is given.
Multicollinearity is a problem for Attitude (2 out of 3 items VIF > 5).

What's the best way to fix this - how can I add *Attitude* to the model?

Even though this is a beginner's question, I am thankful for any insights! Thanks!

[image: Coefficients without Attitude]
[image: Coefficients without Attitude]

Comment: Is this your complete model?

Comment: The Privacy Concern is a Third Order Construct but I exported the latent variable scores, so this is my "final" model -- as described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRND-H-hQQw

Comment: Switching sign does not mean that they are contradictory - sometimes this is expected. Think about the theoretical causal framework of your constructs.